# Attribute routing throws a "multiple controller types found" error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I' m just using Attribute Routing and really can' t get some routes to work

This is my **ProjectsController.cs** routing attributes

```
[RouteArea("Admin")]
[Route("Projects/{action}/{id?}")]
public class ProjectsController : Controller
```

This is my **RepresentativesController.cs** routing attributes

```
[RouteArea("Admin")]
[RoutePrefix("Projects")]
[Route("Representatives/{action}/{id?}")]
public class RepresentativesController : Controller
```

and this is folder structure (although it shouldn' t be needed):

```
-Areas
 |-Admin
   |-Controllers
     |-ProjectsController.cs
     |-RepresentativesController.cs
```

I can' manage to browse this Url for example

```
/Admin/Projects/Representatives/Index
```

because I keep getting this error:

```
Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.

The request has found the following matching controller types: 
FasecItaliaLabMVC.Areas.Admin.Controllers.ProjectsController
FasecItaliaLabMVC.Areas.Admin.Controllers.RepresentativesController
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify routes, possible options:

1. Remove `{id?}` from `[Route("Projects/{action}/{id?}")]` because currently `{id?}` is matched to `index`.
2. Extend route e.g. `[Route("Projects/Main/{action}/{id?}")]`
3. Remove route prefix `[RoutePrefix("Projects")]`

Hard to tell single solution, it depends on your controllers.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the Projects controller doesn' t have an action called Representatives. Is option 1 still valid?

Comment: Give it a try, it should be valid solution.

Comment: It is a valid solution... What I was saying is that I shouldn' t get the error since the ProjectsController doesn' t have an action called Representatives, or am I wrong?

Comment: First of all it finds valid route and if valid route is found it looks for controller. In your case two valid routes are found and error is thrown because it is unclear where to look for action. It doesn't matter if action exists or not.